# QGIS 3.10.3 crashes removing a polygon layer created via script

Tags: qgis, polygon

I created a polygon layer from a line layer(qgis:linestopolygons), set its style ('qgis:setstyleforvectorlayer') and put it in a group of layer table.
Everythings works but when script has completed and I try to remove the new poligon layer or I try to begin a new project by the relative menu commands, QGIS crashes.
If I load the same layer with menu command, then I can remove it without QGIS crash. Below the code:

alg_params = {
            'INPUT':stats['EstraiTramiteEspressione']['OUTPUT'],
            'OUTPUT':self.dlg.mQgsFileWidget_3.filePath() + "/pol_cdl.shp"
        }
        outputs['DaLineeAPoligoni'] = processing.run('qgis:linestopolygons', alg_params)

```
    vlayer_pol = QgsVectorLayer(self.dlg.mQgsFileWidget_3.filePath() + "/pol_cdl.shp", "pol_cdl","ogr")  
    crs = vlayer_pol.crs()
    crs.createFromId(4978) 
    vlayer_pol.setCrs(crs) 
    QgsProject.instance().addMapLayer(vlayer_pol,False)

    sty=self.dlg.mQgsFileWidget_5.filePath()+'/cdl.qml'
    alg_params = {'INPUT': vlayer_pol, 'STYLE': sty}
    outputs = processing.run('qgis:setstyleforvectorlayer', alg_params) 

    #crea gruppo per tipo e trasferisce layer
    groupName = tipo + " da " + dap + " a " + ap
    root = QgsProject.instance().layerTreeRoot()
    group = root.addGroup(groupName) 
    group.insertChildNode(0, QgsLayerTreeLayer(vlayer_pol))      root.findLayer(vlayer_pol.id()).setCustomProperty("showFeatureCount", True)

    if self.dlg.checkBox_13.isChecked():
        return
```